# temporizar imagen en html

Tags: javascript, html, html5, javascript-objeto

necesito temporizar la imagen para que aparezca unos segundos y desaparezca pero no me esta funcionando el codigo, ¿me pueden ayudar?

`

```js
function mostrar(id){ img=document.getElementById(id); 
                      img.innerHTML='<img  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIAYA8hTE0vOHlJm4y8DlUYvC9GTcKuJtwWze-7RtzNyb9SGi6JWnmeYgqAkHBVWflaDM&usqp=CAU">';
                    setTimeout(mostrar, 4000);}
```

```html
<button  onClick="mostrar('imagen')" >Aceptar</button>
<div id='imagen'></div>
```

`

Comment: Darle click para que aparezca y que unos segundos después desaparezca?

Comment: eso es, que desaparezca a los segundos

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

Modificando los atributos `style` del elemento que quieras ocultar.

***JavaScript:***

```
function mostrar(id){ 
    img=document.getElementById(id); 
    img.innerHTML='<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIAYA8hTE0vOHlJm4y8DlUYvC9GTcKuJtwWze-7RtzNyb9SGi6JWnmeYgqAkHBVWflaDM&usqp=CAU">';

    setTimeout(() => {
       img.style.display = "none"
       //imgHidde.style.visibility = "collapse"
       //imgHidde.style.visibility = "hidden"
    }, 4000);
}
```

***Diferencias:***
Creditos: [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695813/difference-between-visibilitycollapse-and-displaynone)

> `visibility:hidden` significa que, a diferencia de ella, la etiqueta
> no es visible, pero se le asigna espacio en la página. La etiqueta se
> representa, simplemente no se ve en la página.
>
> `display:none` significa que la etiqueta en cuestión no aparecerá en
> la página en absoluto (aunque aún puede interactuar con ella a través
> del DOM). No habrá espacio asignado para ello entre las otras
> etiquetas.
>
> `visibility:collapse` Oculta un elemento por completo (para que no ocupe
> ningún espacio en el diseño), pero solo cuando el elemento es un elemento de tabla.

***HTML:***

```
<button  onClick="mostrar('imagen')" >Aceptar</button>

 <div id='imagen'></div>
```

***Alternativa para capturar el evento Click del botón:***

***HTML BOTON:***

```
<button id="btnShowImage">Aceptar</button>
```

***JS:***

```
let imgHidde = document.getElementById('imagen')
let btn = document.getElementById('btnShowImage')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imgHidde.innerHTML='<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIAYA8hTE0vOHlJm4y8DlUYvC9GTcKuJtwWze-7RtzNyb9SGi6JWnmeYgqAkHBVWflaDM&usqp=CAU">';      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que usar el **`setTimeout()`** para que se oculte dicho elemento cada cierto tiempo, para ocultarlo le tendrías que agregar la propiedad **`display: none`** dentro del **`setTimeout()`**, sería algo así:

```js
function mostrar(id) {
  img = document.getElementById(id);
  img.style.display = 'block';
  img.innerHTML = '<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIAYA8hTE0vOHlJm4y8DlUYvC9GTcKuJtwWze-7RtzNyb9SGi6JWnmeYgqAkHBVWflaDM&usqp=CAU">';

  setTimeout(() => {
    img.style.display = 'none';
  }, 4000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mostrar('imagen')" >Aceptar</button>
<div id='imagen'></div>
```