# No puedo cerra un modal de bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

El modal contiene un formulario, la idea es que al enviar el formulario y una vez tenga el contenido del mismo el modal se cierre.

```
<div id="welcomeModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen modal-dialog-scrollable">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Gestor de gastos</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body pt-5 px-1 text-center">
          <div class="display-2">Bienvenido!</div>
          <p class="fs-4">Antes de empezar define el nombre de tu cuenta princial.</p>
          <form>
            <div class="mt-5 mx-5">
                <input type="text" id="princialAccountName" class="form-control" id="principalAccount" aria-describedby="help" placeholder="Nombre de tu cuenta principal." required>
                <div id="help" class="form-text text-start">Este nombre solo es una referencia a la cuenta bancaria verdadera.</div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mt-4">Ingresar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
const manager = new Manager()

let welcomeModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('welcomeModal'), { keyboard: false })
welcomeModal.show()

const welcomModalElement = document.getElementById('welcomeModal')
welcomModalElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const princialAccountName = document.getElementById('princialAccountName').value
    if (!princialAccountName) {
        manager.logAccount(princialAccountName)
        // En este momento tendria que cerrar el modal
        welcomModalElement.innerHTML = ''
        document.body.removeChild(welcomModalElement)
    }
})
```

Como ya dije antes necesito que el modal se cierre luego de obtener el valor de *princialAccountName* y pasarselo a la clase *manager*, pero no me estaria funcionando.

Tambien prove con el metodo que provee el mismo bootstrap, pero tampoco me da resultados.

```
const manager = new Manager()

let welcomeModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('welcomeModal'), { keyboard: false })
welcomeModal.show()
const welcomModalElement = document.getElementById('welcomeModal')
welcomModalElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const princialAccountName = document.getElementById('princialAccountName').value
    if (!princialAccountName) {
        manager.logAccount(princialAccountName)
        // Metodos de bootstrap
        welcomeModal.hide()
        welcomeModal.dispose()
    }
})
```

[Documentacion de bootstrap 5 que estube usando.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

Comment: Mira esto a ver si te funciona [Oculta elemento HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/569202/temporizar-imagen-en-html/569203#569203)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato, pero no, tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la condicional.

```
let welcomeModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('welcomeModal'), { keyboard: false })
welcomeModal.show()
const welcomModalElement = document.getElementById('welcomeModal')
welcomModalElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Aqui esta el texto del formulario
    const principalAccountName = document.getElementById('princialAccountName').value
    // Se valida si es un string vacio o uno lleno
    if (!principalAccountName) {
        manager.logAccount(principalAccountName)         
        welcomeModal.hide()
    }
})
```

El problema es que:

!'lepiz' = **falce**

!' ' = **true**

Entonces para que funcione la condicion deberia ser así:

```
if (!!principalAccountName) {
        manager.logAccount(principalAccountName)         
        welcomeModal.hide()
}
```

En conclucion. El modal nunca se cerraba porque nunca se llegaba a esa parte.